# Chrome Extension to move multiple tabs to new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am trying to build a chrome extension that will move all the tabs to the left of the current tab to a new window.

When I execute the following code, it moves each left tab in its own window. So if there are 2 tabs to the left of the current tab, it will create 2 windows with 1 tabs in each window. How do I get it so that it only moves all the left tabs to a new window (ie: it does not create a new window for each tab to the left of the current tab)?

```
function groupTabsToTheLeft(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if (tabs[i].index < tab.index) {  
            chrome.windows.create({"tabId": tabs[i].id});           
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Based on OP's extra requirements, the solution below has the following specifications:

- Moves the tabs on the left of the active tab to a new window.
- Configures the new window to have the same location, size and state as the original window.
- Removes the empty tab created by default in the new window.
- Gives the focus to the original window (upon completion).

---

You could do it like this:

1. Get the required info from the active window (using **[chrome.windows.get](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-get)**).
2. Determine which tab IDs should be moved.
3. Create an empty window (using **[chrome.windows.create](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)**).
4. Move them all to the window created in step (1) (using **[chrome.tabs.move](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-move)**).
5. Controle the exact behaviour of the newly created window and moved tabs (using **[chrome.windows.update](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-update)**, **[chrome.tabs.remove](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove)**).

---

A sample **background.js** would look like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    /* Get the `tab`'s window along with its containing tabs */
    chrome.windows.get(tab.windowId, { populate: true }, function(oldWin) {
        /* Determine which tabs should be moved
         * (i.e. are on the left of `tab` */
        var tabs = oldWin.tabs;
        var tabsToMove = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if (tabs[i].index < tab.index) {
                tabsToMove.push(tabs[i].id);
            }
        }

        /* If there are any tabs to move... */
        if (tabsToMove.length > 0) {
            /* Create a new window with the same
             * location and size as the original */
            chrome.windows.create({
                top: oldWin.top,
                left: oldWin.left,
                width: oldWin.width,
                height: oldWin.height,
                focused: false
            }, function(newWin) {
                /* Remove the new, empty tab created by default */
                chrome.tabs.query({
                    windowId: newWin.id
                }, function(tabsToClose) {
                    /* Update the window's state (e.g. "maximized") */
                    chrome.windows.update(newWin.id, { state: oldWin.state });

                    /* Move the tabs to the newly created window */
                    chrome.tabs.move(tabsToMove, {
                        windowId: newWin.id,
                        index: -1
                    }, function() {
                        /* Close any tabs that pre-existed (i.e. 1 empty tab)
                         * [Do not do this BEFORE moving the tabs,
                         *  or the window will be empty and will close] */
                        var lastIdx = tabsToClose.length - 1;
                        tabsToClose.forEach(function(t, idx) {
                            chrome.tabs.remove(t.id);
                            if (idx === lastIdx) {
                                chrome.windows.update(oldWin.id, {
                                    focused: true
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

For the sake of completeness, the accompanying **manifest.js** could look like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": true,

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
        //"default_icon": {
        //    "19": "img/icon19.png",
        //    "38": "img/icon38.png"
        //},
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What it does is that it moves the right tabs to the new window and creates a new blank tab in that new window. To move the left tabs to a new window just replace the greater than sign with the less than sign in your if statement? **Why does it create a new blank tab?** How do I get it to not create that new blank tab? When it moves the tabs to a new window, **why does it resize the window?** I would like the new windows to be in the same state as they were before I moved them to a new window.

Comment: Also. **How do you get the current tab to be the active tab after moving all the left tabs to a new window?**

Comment: @Ishan: See my updated answer above. Also, if this answer helped you solve your problem, please **[mark it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Comment: @Ishan: Did you try out the updated code ? Did it solve the problem ?

Comment: @Ishan: I copy the code from my post and load it as an unpacked extension. Then, when I click the browser-action: 1. it creates a new window with the same location and size as the original 2. Moves all tabs that where on the left of the active tab to the new window 3. Deletes the originally empty tab created on the new window 4. Gives the focus to the originally active tab. It is strange you say "it just opens a new window". Did you copy the code exactly as it appears in my post ? Did you get any errors in background pages console log ?

Comment: Yes, I copied the code from your post and loaded it as an unpacked extension. I tested the unpacked extension on 2 different versions of chrome. In version 19, it just opens a new window, but in version 23, it does exactly what you said.

Comment: Why does it not work in version 19. In version 19, I get this error message in the console: `Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'index': Value must not be less than 0. schema_generated_bindings:57 `

Comment: @Ishan: This is probably due to some change in the API since version 19. In the current version, setting `index: -1` in `chrome.tabs.move(...)` appends the tabs after the window's open tabs. In version 19 it was probably different. In any case, since there are not meant to be any other tabs open at the end, you could replace it with `index: 0` (which will work in both versions).

Comment: @Ishan: Did you try setting `index: 0` as suggested in my comment above ? Did it work for you ? Please marke the answer as accepted if find it appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tabs[i].index < tab.index) {  
        **chrome.windows.create**({"tabId": tabs[i].id});           
        } else {
            break;
        }
```

Your Problem is that every time you get into the if you create a new window.
So you only have to create a new Window for the first Tab and the other Tabs you must add to the created Window.